# Multiple instance of rundll32.exe found, but what are they doing ? Suspious?

Tags: windows-7, virus, rundll32.exe

I recently found there are always two instance of rundll32.exe running on my computer. I was able to retrieve info about modules that are using them, but what are these modules? Am I infected by a hard to remove virus ? Or worse, my computer is hacked?

```
Image Name                     PID Modules                                     
========================= ======== ============================================
rundll32.exe                  2892 ntdll.dll, wow64.dll, wow64win.dll,         
                                   wow64cpu.dll                                
rundll32.exe                  2956 ntdll.dll, kernel32.dll, KERNELBASE.dll,    
                                   USER32.dll, GDI32.dll, LPK.dll, USP10.dll,  
                                   msvcrt.dll, imagehlp.dll, ADVAPI32.dll,     
                                   sechost.dll, RPCRT4.dll, IMM32.DLL,         
                                   MSCTF.dll, saHook.dll, ole32.dll,           
                                   OLEAUT32.dll, uxtheme.dll, dwmapi.dll,      
                                   CRYPTBASE.dll, CLBCatQ.DLL, CRYPTSP.dll,    
                                   rsaenh.dll, RpcRtRemote.dll, HcApi.dll,     
                                   HcThe.dll
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get more info on high-CPU rundll32.exe process?](http://superuser.com/questions/67932/how-can-i-get-more-info-on-high-cpu-rundll32-exe-process) What does your research tell you about those modules? Are the files located in system folders or elsewhere? Have you run any malware/rootkit scans?

Comment: the second instance shown looks normal for base internal workings can't say i recognize wow64*

Comment: @Karan I searched the first couple of ones, and processlibrary.com says they are windows os modules.    But this one ----saHook.dll  has a result of unknow and unsecure level,   another module with similiar name called 180saHook.dll  is a known spyware according to processlibrary.   How can I find this file in my computer?

Comment: @shadowmaster: Did you look at the question I linked to and try Process Explorer?

Comment: @Karan  I did, and rundll32.exe points to C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rundll32.exe    and    C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe   ;   and I found that  saHook.dll points to c:\PROGRA~2\mcafee\SITEAD~1\x64\saHook.dll which is McAfee anti-virus .     Looks legit.